# Why does using two-finger scroll on the Windows 8.1 start menu result in a click on the center of the screen?

Tags: windows-8.1, touchpad, scrolling

I have two brand new Asus N550JV laptops here at work. I took them out of the box, installed the Windows Updates required to get the Windows 8.1 update to install, ran through that, then ran through all the remaining Windows updates.

On one of the two machines, I installed all the newest drivers on ASUS' web site for the N550JV. On the other one, I left it alone (there are various Win 8.1 related driver issues that need correction).

On both machines, if you open the Start screen and then use the two-finger scroll, when you let go of the scroll and then move the cursor it clicks on the exact center of the screen. When scrolling from the main Start screen to the All Apps menu, this results in launching ASUS Install and closing the Start screen. I uninstalled ASUS Install, thinking this was the issue, but it then just started clicking on ASUS Instant Key Menu.

The theory that it's simply clicking in the center of the screen was further cemented by using the arrow key in the bottom left of the Start screen to go to All Apps, then two-finger-scrolling back up to the regular Start screen. It launched Maps... the tile in the center of the Start screen.

This is absolutely driving me up the wall. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the Asus default touchpad driver, plus the newest version available from their web page as of March 2014, is buggy on Windows 8.1 and causes this behaviour.

I solved my problem by removing the Asus driver and installing a generic Elan Tech touchpad driver. I think the install package came from a Samsung notebook because it displays a Samsung logo on the advanced driver settings page.

Installing this driver entirely eliminates the ability to two-finger-scroll down to the 'all apps' section of the Start Screen - the Asus driver appears to temporarily emulate a touchscreen at times (which, incidentally, has the annoying habit of making the taskbar icon for the on-screen touch keyboard reappear).

The generic Elan Tech driver behaves consistently as a touchpad and doesn't do anything annoying, so I'm calling this one solved. Maybe Asus will update their driver in the future, but I'm not too worried about it.

Comment: Extra information: the good driver was 11.7.85, in spite of there being newer versions, and I had to do the install process twice through the device manager - once on AC and once on battery (super weird).